# Disallowing third party hosted images or moving the hosted image to SO?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, images

A lot of the time when working on projects with outdated frameworks or versions I had to lookup some quite old questions and answers, and whenever there is an image attached that is from a third-party site, there is a high probably that the image would not load and that would decrease the quality of the question/answer.

From what I can see Stack Overflow still allows users to embed images that are hosted on third party sites. This is not a question of **if** that image will simply disappear but a question of **when**. Third-party sites shut down, delete old data, and do stuff to images that are out of our control.

My suggestion is that whenever someone wants to embed a third-party hosted image or links to an image, the image is downloaded and moved to a source that is controlled by Stack Overflow (I believe currently images that are uploaded directly are on Imgur). This would preserve images and question/answer quality for the foreseeable future.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that all those images would change license to what Stack or Imgur has?

Comment: If the answer isn't helpful (any more), downvote it and move on; in truth an image being required for an answer to be *good* is generally frowned upon anyway as it means some users can't consume the answer (such as those using screen readers). If the question, however, is still applicable for the problem you are having, then place a bounty on it, and explain that the answers are outdated and you are looking for a new one.

Comment: @Larnu You do make a fair point and I absolutely agree that answers should avoid relying on images. However the fact still remains that some very useful answers still use images. In my opinion we should strive to make sure that answers are useful to people in the future and preserving images is one of the ways of doing that. Although as Scratte mentioned there might be some licensing issues. About the accessibility issue maybe we can encourage people to describe in detail what is going on in the embbeded image so it still useful?

Comment: *"However the fact still remains that some very useful answers still use images."* If the images are required, and those images can't be accessed anymore, because the URL is dead, surely therefore the answer *isn't* useful anymore, no? You could, also, add a comment on the answer to let the user know the link is dead and they might provide a new image (and better yet add text to explain what the image demonstrates).

Comment: Can you add one or more examples? Most [Imgur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur) image links *aren't* broken (though it *does* happen from time to time) and most images (more than 99%) are on Imgur.

Comment: @PeterMortensen in my quick search I couldn't find any. I am certain some exist but this is a much lesser problem than what I remembered. My bad...

Comment: *"the image is downloaded and moved to a source that is controlled by Stack Overflow"* - It only takes one image which is actually commercial for that to really [bite you hard in the behind](https://www.videogameschronicle.com/news/capcom-faces-a-12m-lawsuit-after-data-leak-allegedly-shows-it-stole-photos-for-resident-evil/).  Don't mess with images for which you cannot prove the source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moving my comments into an answer, while expanding on them a little.

> whenever there is an image attached that is from a third-party site, there is a high probably that the image would not load and that would decrease the quality of the question/answer.

The answer to this is very likely to downvote the answer if it is no longer helpful. The usefulness of an answer can change and dead links are a very easy way for an old post (question or answer) to lose usefulness; especially when the link is required to be able to properly consume the answer supplied.

If you wish, however, you can leave a comment on the answer (unfortunately it's now currently difficult to see if a user is still active on the community unless they have recently contributed) in the hope that the user edits the answer and lets you know they have done so. If you don't get a response, then likely you would then give the answer a downvote.

As for how to get an answer, if the question is still of good quality, place a bounty on it saying you are looking for new answers because the existing answer(s) are outdated.

If the question is the one that is no longer a good question, because of the dead links to images, and the answers also don't answer your question as you can't consume them (due to details that are specific to the missing content of the question), then you could post a new question. Ensure, however, you cite the question you found and explain *why* your question isn't a duplicate (due to the lack of consumable images) as otherwise it might well be closed as a duplicate.

---

As for the suggestion, this is a little already handled. If you use the Insert Image button in the text editor and paste in a url for an image, then the editor *does* upload that image to https://i.stack.imgur.com. The same is true for if you paste the image into the text editor; it'll be uploaded the the same domain.

The only exception to when an image isn't uploaded to https://i.stack.imgur.com is when you specifically write the markdown for the image. Personally, I don't really see a good reason to force the markdown to be parsed, notice a URL to an image which is being displayed, upload said image to https://i.stack.imgur.com, retrieve the URL for the new image, and then change the URL in the post.

Also, as noted by [Scratte](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/410697/disallowing-third-party-hosted-images-or-moving-the-hosted-image-to-so#comment859566_410697), it could be the user did it for a specific reason, such as due to licencing. We should not enforce the user to accept the licence terms of [so] if they intentionally didn't want to for their image.

Comment: I was not aware of it already being handled. Then this is a non-issue. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: And do not fear the 1 rep "penalty" for downvoting an answer. You'll get it back in no time.

Comment: A counterpoint: We *should* force users to accept Stack Exchange's license terms if they want to contribute to the network.  We force them to for text, why should we exempt images from that requirement?  People reading Stack Exchange content shouldn't be forced to check URLs to determine the license of an image: they should be able to assume it's CC BY-SA, just like everything else here.